# Php page loading as question mark with Mac OSX Lion Webserver

Tags: php, html, macos, webserver

I am having a very strange problem with my Mac OSX Lion Webserver. I have a website that functions fully on a webserver that I pay for but now I am trying to run it locally on my own computer for development. I have set up my Mac webserver to use PHP5 and work with Mysql, and I have copied all of the files that I need to the proper folder. Most of the pages work, both .html and .php files, but there is one page that, when I try to load it, will only load as a question mark. Literally, there is a "?" in the top left corner of the browser window, no debug messages in chrome developer tools, and the only html available when I view source is that of a question mark and generic html formatting tags.

The thing that is even stranger is that if I delete EVERYTHING in the file (blank file with the same filename) and load it, it loads with the SAME QUESTION MARK, that is why I didn't bother posting any code. Additionally, if I rename the file to .html, it loads properly (without the use of php of course).

The filename is login.php, and I don't think the filename matters too much because I have a different login.php in another part of the site that works properly.

If anyone has any insight into this I would really appreciate it.

Thank you!

Comment: do you have a .htaccess file in that directory? if so what are its contents. Also attach a screen shot!

Comment: Are you confident that the server is actually using PHP?

Comment: Use Fiddler to view what is sent over the wire as well.

Comment: I do not have an .htaccess, at least that I can tell. I am confident PHP is being use as I can use it on other pages. I am working with a mac so I cannot use Fiddler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope nobody else has this problem but here is how I fixed it.

After doing a TON of seemingly random stuff, I found that the "question mark" was occurring only when the page was unmodified. With even a small modification, the question mark would disappear to yield a blank page. Eventually all I did was delete the '>' in the last  tag and type it in again and the page worked! I guess it looked right but the character was corrupt or something...sounds stupid but that's what did it.